# Problem with this " straight out of vogue"

Tags: word-meaning

> Rita looked like fashion model "straight out of vogue" with an off shoulder green dress that had a plunging neckline.

What is the meaning of *straight out of vogue*?
I read the dictionary, and I found two definitions; one was *without hesitation*, and the other one was *fashion that is prevalent in particular time*.

Which one is correct? Why?

Comment: That should be *straight out of* Vogue, capitalized.  *Vogue* is a fairly prestigious fashion magazine.

Comment: Actually, *A is straight out of B* in this specific context doesn't specifically relate to *without hesitation*. It's more like *directly, accurately, with no alterations* (i.e. - A is ***exactly like*** something in B).

Answer (score 3):

Of your two alternatives, the first "straight out of" would be more correct.

> [Vogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogue_(magazine))

is a fashion magazine which gets its name from the noun

> vogue

meaning "foremost place in popularity" from the French.

If *something* is

> straight out of Vogue

it means it appears to come directly from the pages of the fashion magazine, highly styled, and highly stylish

[image: here]